# Scaling graph traversals in ArangoDb

Tags: graph, graph-databases, arangodb

I have a tree-like structure, which is actually a directed acyclic graph. A small version shown below.
[image: minimal graph]

At any parent, I want to sum some properties of the sub-tree. Today I'm doing this in AQL using TRAVERSAL and COLLECT based on starting node:

```
for c in traversal(nodes,nodeTree,ch,'inbound',{uniqueness:{vertices:'global'}})
    collect child = ch._id into group
```

Then I can use aggregation on the group. (With ArangoDB 2.8 I believe this can now be done directly in the collect statement.) The uniqueness option solves the problem of duplicates.

**Scaling**

When the tree (graph) grows into a considerable size (10-20k nodes) how will this scale? I need it to be fast, as the user will wait for the response (not a long running job).

I'm thinking of caching values in the nodes and having a *dirty* flag. Then in node 1 could just sum 2 and 3, if they were both *clean*. The *problem* is that 5 is included in both 2 and 3's sums.

How can I solve this? Or is it a non-problem -- are traversals really that quick?

So far I've come up with the idea of having each node include a list of it's subtree-duplicates, which in 1's case would mean the info "5 is included twice". This could be used to subtract this from 1's total. But how would I find this information? I have thought about finding all nodes with >1 parent, then traversing upwards (that's quick) and then *somehow* calculate this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime of the traversal is bounded by the amount of vertices and edges actually touched in the process. So the runtime of the traversal depends on the depth of the paths and the branching factor (how many of those vertices with multiple parents are expected).

The problem with the construct you describe is that the traversal will pick one path from `1` to `5` (say the left one) and sums all the values and eventually returns to `1` to pick the right path. Now it reaches `5` again but this time the search depth is lower than the last time `5` was seen, so it has to actually traverse the subtree on 5 once again because it could now possibly get a larger distance in this path (it does not know that all vertices on this subtree could be reached in shorter distance already). The vertices on this path will not invoke the visitor again but are still traversed and followed which costs time.

I tried to optimize the traversal to validate scaling.
First i registered a new optimized visitor:

```
require("@arangodb/aql/functions").register("test::counter", "function (config, result, vertex) {result[0] = result[0] || {value: 0}; result[0].value += vertex.value}");
```

This visitor sums the values of the vertices in place and directly returns them, so i can get rid of the `COLLECT` statement. And i can use it my AQL:

```
FOR x IN TRAVERSAL(TestVertices, TestEdges, 'TestVertices/0', 'outbound', {uniqueness:{vertices:'global'}, visitor: 'test::counter', maxDepth: 5012})
  RETURN x.value
```

Note here: I have given a `maxDepth` in the options to actually search in high depth, the default is `256`.

My test-tree was basically a chain of `20.000` vertices where every third vertex has an additional edge to a random vertex later in the chain (simulating your described multiple parents problem)

With this traversal i managed to search a depth of `5012` from the root in `~5 secs`. Using a higher depth it growth exponentially.

I assume that your graph has fewer of these multiple parents, so i expect less runtime on your graph.

If you expect a lot more reads then writes you could also consider to compute the sums on each write.
This will slow down the writes but will make all reads instant.

As an example you could use the following AQL in addition when updating a value:

```
LET i = (FOR x IN 1..5012 INBOUND @start TestEdges
           RETURN DISTINCT x) 
  FOR x IN i UPDATE x WITH {sum: x.sum + @add} IN TestVertices
```

With the bind parameters `@add` for the value to add and `@start` for the vertex that is updated. Using this technique your read query is trivial:

```
FOR x IN TestVertices FILTER x._id == @start 
  RETURN x.sum
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Seems like traversals can be reasonably quick. In my case the graph would most likely be wide instead of deep. MaxDepth 50 I'd say.

Comment: I absolutely expect more reads than writes, which is why I'm thinking about caching the sums, like you give an example of. My concern here is 1) a "hot" root (accessed for every write - blocks etc) and 2) being confident the sums are kept correct (a transaction would probably help with that)

Comment: 2) for the correctness you can implement your transaction for multiple AQL queries in a foxx app (https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/index.html)
1) Yes you are right "hot" root might be blocking, but i would actually give it a try and see the performance on simulated data as you expect it (or even the real data) and check if it is actually a problem. The write could probably be fast enough for a user-perceived "non-blocking" because the actual read is always a constant time action. So in comparison the average waiting time for the user may be lower with the blocking root.

Comment: How would this look for ArangoDB v3? Now that there are no visitor functions anymore (with the new traversal syntax)?

Comment: Seems like `collect aggregate` came to the rescue just fine.